# Shift+? for hotkey menu

Tags: feature-request

On both Twitter and Gmail, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> presents a cool menu like this

## Twitter:

[image]

## Gmail:

[image]

I think it would be nice if SE implemented a similar feature

(perhaps simple like the twitter one)

Answer (score 2):

The StackExchange Keyboard userscript ([SEKeyboardShortcuts](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/wiki/Install)) does this.

Comment: Cool, [here's what it looks like](http://i.imgur.com/xyAWd.png). Be best if it was official!

Comment: @bobobobo, admittedly, the ui could using some lovin'.  If you're so inclined, feel free to fork and submit a pull request!

Comment: @rebecca eeeeek! why not just copy the CSS from Twitter?